# how to convert the yaml to spreadsheet?

Tags: ruby, yaml, spreadsheet

how can i use ruby to convert a yaml file and keep on the indent format over cells to spreadsheet file.

the yaml file like this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.10/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml

Comment: You need to be a little more specific about your goal here... How is the Yaml interacting with a spreadsheet and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to export to .xls?

Comment: sorry, i wanna the results like this http://cl.ly/3r1V353t0N0D263c3w1v

Comment: http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv - You can get algoritm here, I think

Answer (score 4):

You haven't clearly stated what you want this spreadsheet to look like so I can't be specific but you can use the [YAML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html) library to read the file into a data structure, then convert the data structure into one like a table (array of arrays of strings) then use the [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CSV.html) library to output it to a file.

```
require 'yaml'
require 'csv'

yaml_txt = File.read 'input.yaml'
yaml_data = YAML.load yaml_txt

csv_table = [
    [1,'hello world', true], 
    ['a', 'b', 3.14159, 'c', 2, 3e8], 
    [nil, 'another row', 'bla']
]
#replace this^ with something that converts the yaml_data into a 2D array

File.open 'output.csv', 'w' do |f|
    f.puts( csv_table.map do |row|
        CSV.generate_line row
    end.join "\n" )
end
```

The current example will produce:

```
1,hello world,true
a,b,3.14159,c,2,300000000.0
,another row,bla
```

in output.csv.

You can then open the CSV spreadsheet with the following options:

[image]

Comment: And if he wants to "preserve indentation", he could replace every leading pair of spaces with an empty column in CSV output. I am just not sure how Excel would handle variable number of columns per record when importing CSV created that way.

Answer (score 1):

think, it's better to join rows with an empty string rather than "\n"